# Doppler effect when source and observer are in different media

Tags: waves, acoustics, doppler-effect

According to what I learnt about Doppler effect, on moving the source and/or the observer relative to medium, there is a change of frequency heard by the observer.

> f(new) = f(old)(v(sound)+v(observer))/(v(sound)-v(source))

---

But, recently I came across a problem where the source and observer both were separated by water, and were going towards each other with equal speeds v/5, downward and upward respectively.
[[image: source and observer separated with water1]

---

The problem stated that we have to find the wavelength of sound heard by O if S emits sound of frequency f.
Velocity of sound in air is v and in water is 4v.

---

To get the answer, I first found the frequency as received by the surface of water, i.e., (5/4)f. Then, I calculated the frequency as heard by O, in water, i.e., (21/16)f.
So, the wavelength comes out to be (64/21)(v/f). But the answer given is (16/5)(v/f).
That would mean the observer heard the frequency as received by water surface (the 5/4 f value).
Have I done any error in applying the principle of Doppler effect in this case?

Comment: Hi, can you please edit so we can match your "5/4 f" to the "v/5"  more easily?   But  in any case, I suspect you aren't calculating the change in frequency when a sound of $f_{air}$ in air enters the water, taking on a new  $f_{water}$  before considering the subsequent doppler shift due to the observer **O** moving.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the 5/4 f refers to the frequency of sound measured by a device on the surface of water. The frequency is emitted by S (above water) and is equal to f. As for new frequency in water, I believe frequency doesn't change on change of medium. Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: thanks - you are correct that the frequency of the propagating wave won't change; just lambda.  Sorry about that misdirection.  The only difference between this problem and the in-air problem with a net "approach velocity" of  2v/5 is the different speed of sound once the wave enters the water.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft can you please specify whether the "approach velocity" is the relative velocity, or some other? Also, while solving, I treated the case in two parts: first, when the sound waves hit the water surface with a different frequency, 5/4 f due to Doppler, then these sound waves travel through water with a different velocity to be received by O with an even different frequency ( it's in the body of the question) so, the different speed of sound can't be the problem here. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: Your method is correct, except in the very last step. The velocity of sound wave for the observer is not $4v$, but $4v+\frac{v}{5}$ as the observer itself is moving towards the source of waves.

Comment: @AumkaarPranav thank you for the observation, but I still don't see how the wavelength comes out to be equal to the answer given in the book. Could you please write the solution as an answer? Thank you :)

Comment: @RS123xy I just corrected the value of wave velocity that you've used along with the frequency value $21f/16$ to get the final wavelength. It's simple division of wave velocity by the frequency.

Comment: Pranav is correct. Take 4V+V/5 as wavelength would change owing to media used over here
Factoring the same would get the answer and understanding on concept juxtaposition. Thanks Er.Ritul Kumar

Comment: Alternatively you may use new lembda= old lembda-(V source × time period)